# After typing a URL in Google Chrome, how can I launch the address without pressing the Return/Enter key?

Tags: google-chrome

After typing a URL in Google Chrome, how can I launch the address without pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? I have been trying to figure out a way to do this for a long time. How can I achieve this?

---

Sorry, I didn't say very clearly. I meant, not to use keyboard, but use mouse. How can I let it *GO*? I didn't see any button or place I can click

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, how long do you want Chrome to wait before it launches the URL? Do you want it to happen when you type `.com` or `.net` for example?

Comment: Chrome beta/dev versions should have instant rendering of pages soon as you type them, should be available in `about:flags`. Still requires a confirmation that you did visit to the page

Comment: Mac SL. Right away.

Comment: @AndersLind, how does it know when you are done then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Sorry, I didn't say very clearly. I meant, not to use keyboard, but use mouse. How can I let it GO? Thanks. I didn't see any button or place I can click

There's no dedicated "go" button, clicking on the URL will start the request to the link.

[image]

---

As for instant rendering, Chrome beta/dev versions should have instant rendering of pages soon as you type them, should be available in `about:flags`. Still requires a confirmation that you did visit to the page - you can "confirm" this by clicking on the URL you just typed in or by hitting enter

Comment: By clicking URL is not working, at least for me, on Mac SL.

Comment: I meant the URL in the dropdown that comes *under* the address bar, not in the address bar itself @AndersLind

Answer (score 5):

type in URL box ,select all and copy ,right click and choose paste and go ...

[image: Screenshot]